# Getting "Too much recursion" error while using jQuery form plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery form plugin to submit my form. It has a file element and when I am submitting it I am getting "too much recursion" in Firefox. It looks fine in IE 8. It works fine if I submit the form without selecting any file. Any idea?

I am calling `ajaxForm()` method this way.
`jQuery("#myForm").ajaxForm();`

Code Looks like below:

HTML Form:

```
<form action="someaction.do" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myForm">

To : <input type="text" value=""  name="subject"/>
Attachment : <input type="file" value="" name="attachement"/>

<input type="submit" value="Send"/>

</form>
```

Loading the following scripts

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery/jquery-1.6.js">    </script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

While form is submitting ,
    `jQuery("#myForm").ajaxForm()`

Comment: Are you using the jQuery validation plugin?

Comment: No I am not using validation plugin. Just using form plugin to submit a form, which has a file element in it

Comment: Try replacing `styleId` with just `id` and let me know.

Comment: Hi Usman, I have to use it because that's for struts tag. It is being rendered as id only in the HTMl page.

Comment: Can you please post your full JS code?

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  
  
  jQuery("#myForm").ajaxForm();
    });

Comment: I can't find anything with Form Plugin, is your server side script doing recursive redirects? When commenting please mention me using @Usman , so that I get notified :)

Comment: @Usman No the issue seems to be with Firefox and Form plugin. I brought FF to 3.6 [Which I believed a better version]. It works fine now. I had version 8 before. Thanks for the support